# .htaccess redirection after rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In .htaccess file I have following code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteRule ^home home.php [NC]
```

Which rewrites localhost/xvwa/home.php to localhost/xvwa/home

Now, my problem is that I can still access localhost/xvwa/home.php.
I tried to make 301 redirection but I keep getting forbbiden error.
How do make redirection to localhost/xvwa/home when users trie to go on localhost/xvwa/home.php?

Part II

home.php include several other .php files like header.php and footer.php-> how to prevent users from directly accessing these files-> also is it better to put forbbiden error or missing error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below rules,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xvwa/home.php
RewriteRule ^ /xvwa/home [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^home home.php [NC,L,END]

# deny access
RewriteRule ^(header|footer)\.php - [F,L,NC]
```

Comment: Tnx for quick answer, but unfortunately it didn't solved my problem-> I can still go directly on home.php and it doesn't redirect at all

Comment: where are you using the rules

Comment: .htaccess file in the same folder as home.php (xvwa folder)  / deny access rule works only redirect doesn't

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thank you so much. Just one more question.  I used your deny access rule and it works perfectly except for home_content.php  http://imgur.com/a/vWITk)                                                         # deny access
RewriteRule ^(header|footer|panel|include|home_content)\.php - [F,L,NC]

Comment: mmhhh, if it is in directory where you are using the rules it should work and if it is not working even after that, raise a new question regarding the problem, please accept this as an answer if helpful.